# my scrape brush is weird

Tags: sculpting, sculpt

When I use scrape brush on right side, that's okay.

[image]

But let's go into next photo.

[image]

This is result of the other side from mirror x axis. This is problem.

I would expect to show me the same result.

Why did this happen, and how can I solve it?

[image]

[image: **enter image description here**]

[image]

These are the brush currently setting.

- This this is the topology of the esh in edit mode

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you let us, see the topology of the mesh? you will need to go to edit mode.

Comment: If your model is going to be symmetrical, try clicking on the 'symmetrize' option in the last image you posted. That will make sure that blender has the exact same mesh on both sides, which could make a difference.

Comment: Michael Ben David/ updated  my question. please check out again

Comment: Brenticus/  first of all thanks for your comment. i already know about symmetrize option but i really want to know why mirror perfectly doesn't work even if i'm using mirror x axis.

Answer (score 0):

ok when there are parts of your mesh with more depth of detail this bug happens, because the detail size that you are using its more bigger than the detail size that containts in that area or part of the mesh, so to fix it change the detail size to the proper size that was used in that area. nevertheless with this "bug" (its not a bug actually) you can easily optimize your mesh if it gets too over loaded of polygons for example. also if you dont see anything happen, just add some geometry with the sculpt draw brush and then use the scrape brush in that area again.

Answer (score 0):

this happens when one side of your mesh is different to the other side of the mesh.  in order for the mirror x to work properly both sides need to be pretty exact.